# ERC-20 converter - How will it be possible for someone holding AGI tokens on an exchange to know whether they have ERC-20 AGI or Cardano Native AGI?

Tags: token, erc20, converter

When ERC-20 tokens are are converted from Ethereum to Cardano, is it incumbent on the token holder to know that which wallet they can be deposited into?

What happens if say someone holding Eth native AGI tokens tries to deposit unconverted tokens into a Daedalus address or vice versa? How will it be possible for someone holding AGI tokens on an exchange to know whether they have ERC-20 AGI or Cardano Native AGI?

Answer (score 1):

The original Ethereum tokens are known as AGI tokens

The translated tokens that are Cardano tokens are AGIX tokens.  The X at the end of the name differentiates them.